# PTES: Differences between Internet Footprint, OSINT and footprinting

Tags: penetration-test

I'm trying to understand what the differences are between an *Internet Footprint*, *OSINT* and *footprinting*. I'm reading the [pentest-standard](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Main_Page) and they seem the same.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the PTES correctly, [OSINT](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Intelligence_Gathering#OSINT) occurs in the process first, including the element [Internet Footprint](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Intelligence_Gathering#Individual), and finally [Footprinting](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Intelligence_Gathering#Footprinting).

This document correlates tools to those processes -- http://www.nothink.org/metasploit/documentation/metasploit_msf_analysis_ptes.pdf -- pages 5 to the mid-bottom of page 10 are OSINT, bottom half of page 9 to the same (mid-page 10) are Internet Footprint, while Footprinting is bottom of page 10 to page 15.

Comment: Hey, the page you've documented is now missing, s their any chance we can have that retrieved if you have it stored!?

Comment: Link has been updated. Thank you for notifying me that the link was no-longer valid.